# shell find - controlling the file path

Tags: linux, find

I am using the following command in my makefile:

```
LOCAL_FILES = $(shell find $(COMMON_PATH)/ -type f -name '*.cpp')
```

The result are of the following form:

```
someDirectory/Common/...
```

I would like the result to not include the `someDirectory/` part.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%P` specifier to `-printf` will print the part of the pathname *after* the search directory.

```
find ... -printf '%P\n'
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: @Reinier: Are you using GNU find?

Comment: Aha - I did not realize there was more than one `find`. I am using BSD find which apparently does not support `-printf`

Answer (score 0):

How about piping to e.g. `sed` and have it remove it?

Something like:

```
LOCAL_FILES = $(shell find $(COMMON_PATH)/ -type f -name '*.cpp' | sed 's@someDirectory/@@')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pipe it to sed if you have sed like so

```
$(shell find $(COMMON_PATH)/ -type f -name '*.cpp') | sed -e 's/.*\///g
```

I think that should work not certain my syntax is correct but i think so.

Answer (score 0):

The `-printf '%P\n'` solution is elegant. If you are not using GNU `find` though then you can solve your problem by using the `$(subst from,to,text)` `make` function:

```
LOCAL_FILES = $(subst $(COMMON_PATH)/,,$(shell find $(COMMON_PATH) -type f -name '*.cpp'))
```

This replaces any occurrence of `$(COMMON_PATH)/` by an empty string. Note that this will remove the `$(COMMON_PATH)/` string twice in the unlikely event that it occurs twice in the path of a file.